# P-value for partial (rank) correlation coefficient

Tags: r, correlation, p-value

I use "nlrx" R package for sensitivity analysis of my model, and I would like to investigate the output of this sensitivity analysis. The developers of the package already put a lot of information [here](https://docs.ropensci.org/nlrx/articles/sensitivity.html#example-2-latin-hypercube-sampling), and they provided an example R code (see below) to calculate partial (rank) correlation coefficient (PCC). But their example does not calculate p-value. I would like to know how I can modify the code, so it calculates both PCC and p-value for each metric and parameter. Thank you in advance!

```
library(tidyverse)
input <- getsim(nl, "siminput") %>%    # Take input parameter matrix
  dplyr::select(names(getexp(nl, "variables"))) %>%  # Select variable parameters only
  dplyr::rename_all(~str_replace_all(., c("-" = "_", "\\s+" = "_"))) # Remove - and space characters.

output <- getsim(nl, "simoutput") %>%   # Take simulation output
  dplyr::group_by(`random-seed`, siminputrow) %>% # Group by random seed and siminputrow
  dplyr::summarise_at(getexp(nl, "metrics"), list(mean=mean, sd=sd)) %>% # Aggregate output
  dplyr::ungroup() %>%  # Ungroup
  dplyr::select(-`random-seed`, -siminputrow) %>%  # Only select metrics
  dplyr::rename_all(~str_replace_all(., c("-" = "_", "\\s+" = "_", "\\[" = "_", "\\]" = "_", "=" = ""))) # Remove - and space characters.

# Perform pcc for each output separately (map)
pcc.result <- purrr::map(names(output), function(x) sensitivity::pcc(X=input, y=output[,x], nboot = 100, rank = FALSE)) 

pcc.result.tidy <- purrr::map_dfr(seq_along(pcc.result), function(x) {
  pcc.result[[x]]$PCC %>% 
    tibble::rownames_to_column(var="parameter") %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(metric = names(output)[x])
})

ggplot(pcc.result.tidy) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~metric) +
  geom_point(aes(x=parameter, y=original, color=metric)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=parameter, ymin=`min. c.i.`, ymax=`max. c.i.`, color=metric), width=0.1)
```

I tried to modify the code already in many different ways. Especially this part, so it can calculate pcc and p-value simultaneously:

```
pcc.result <- purrr::map(names(output), function(x) sensitivity::pcc(X=input, y=output[,x], nboot = 100, rank = FALSE))
```

But I never got the results, except error messages or empty pcc.result.

This code works but provides empty result:

```
pcc.result <- purrr::map(names(output), function(x) {
  res <- sensitivity::pcc(X=input, y=output[,x], nboot = 100, rank = FALSE)
  p_val <- 2 * pt(-abs(res$estimate/res$stderr), df=res$n-2)
  return(c(res$estimate, p_val))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're confident about the asymptotic normality of the sampling distribution, then the code you have is almost right.  The estimates would be in `res$PCC[,1]` and the standard errors in `res$PCC[,3]`.  Here's an example:

```r
library(sensitivity)
library(boot)
n <- 100
X <- data.frame(X1 = runif(n, 0.5, 1.5),
                X2 = runif(n, 1.5, 4.5),
                X3 = runif(n, 4.5, 13.5))

# linear model : Y = X1^2 + X2 + X3
y <- with(X, X1^2 + X2 + X3)

# sensitivity analysis
x <- pcc(X, y, nboot = 100)

p_val <- 2 * pt(-abs(x$PCC[,1]/x$PCC[,3]), df=nrow(x$X)-2)
sprintf("%.3f", p_val)
#> [1] "0.000" "0.000" "0.000"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>